# Kotlin + Arrow + Gson = None?

Tags: kotlin, gson, arrow-kt

I have a model in Kotlin of a simple library of Books and Borrowers where a Book is checked out if it has a Borrower. I use Arrow Option to encode the absence/presence of a Borrower:

```
data class Borrower(val name: Name, val maxBooks: MaxBooks)
data class Book(val title: String, val author: String, val borrower: Option<Borrower> = None)
```

I am having trouble serializing/deserializing these objects to/from JSON in Gson - specifically the representation of an `Option<Borrower>` to a JSON `null` within a Book:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Book100",
    "author": "Author100",
    "borrower": {
      "name": "Borrower100",
      "maxBooks": 100
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Book200",
    "author": "Author200",
    "borrower": null
  }
]
```

My deserialize code:

```
fun jsonStringToBooks(jsonString: String): List<Book> {
    val gson = Gson()
    return try {
        gson.fromJson(jsonString, object : TypeToken<List<Book>>() {}.type)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emptyList()
    }
}
```

I get an empty list. The nearly identical `jsonStringToBorrowers` works fine.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Would using a different JSON library like `kotlinx.serialization` or `Klaxon` be a better idea and how do they do the `null <-> None` thing?

Thank you!

Comment: you should make borrower nullable and then use a library that supports kotlin nullable types. I always use moshi with KotlinJsonAdapterFactory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is a bit hidden by the fact that you don't log the exception before returning an empty list. If you logged that exception you would have gotten this:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke private arrow.core.Option() with no args

This means that Gson doesn't know how to create an `Option` class because it has no public empty constructor. Indeed, `Option` is a sealed class ([hence abstract](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html)) having 2 concrete children classes: `Some` and `None`. In order to get an instance of `Option` you should use one of the factory methods, like `Option.just(xxx)` or `Option.empty()` among the others.

Now, in order to fix your code you need to tell Gson how to deserialize an `Option` class. To do that, you need to register a type adapter to your `gson` object.

A possible implementation is the following:

```
class OptionTypeAdapter<E>(private val adapter: TypeAdapter<E>) : TypeAdapter<Option<E>>() {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun write(out: JsonWriter, value: Option<E>) {
        when (value) {
            is Some -> adapter.write(out, value.t)
            is None -> out.nullValue()
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun read(input: JsonReader): Option<E> {
        val peek = input.peek()
        return if (peek != JsonToken.NULL) {
            Option.just(adapter.read(input))
        } else {
            input.nextNull()
            Option.empty()
        }
    }

    companion object {

        fun getFactory() = object : TypeAdapterFactory {
            override fun <T> create(gson: Gson, type: TypeToken<T>): TypeAdapter<T>? {
                val rawType = type.rawType as Class<*>
                if (rawType != Option::class.java) {
                    return null
                }
                val parameterizedType = type.type as ParameterizedType
                val actualType = parameterizedType.actualTypeArguments[0]
                val adapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(actualType))
                return OptionTypeAdapter(adapter) as TypeAdapter<T>
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You can use it in the following way:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(OptionTypeAdapter.getFactory())
        .create()
    val result: List<Book> = try {
        gson.fromJson(json, TypeToken.getParameterized(List::class.java, Book::class.java).type)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        emptyList()
    }

    println(result)
}
```

That code outputs:

```
[Book(title=Book100, author=Author100, borrower=Some(Borrower(name=Borrower100, maxBooks=100))), Book(title=Book200, author=Author200, borrower=None)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughtful and detailed answer. I appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks for your input here. It seems to me as if this solution only works if the keys are there and null, I would like none to also be used here for cases in which the keys are also missing. Do you have any idea? +

Comment: @ViktorLund for that you either need to create your own adapter for type `Borrower` or have a constructor where all elements have a default value (and use `None` as a default value for `borrower`, as done by the OP). That's because Gson expects classes to have an empty constructor, and if that's not the case it creates instances in an "unsafe" manner (more details [here](https://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2018-05-25-kotlin-gson-nullability.html))